# VB .Net Pass value from loaded form

Tags: vb.net

im currently made project with VB VS2012

i have 2 form, 
form1 contains textbox and button, this button is to open form2.
in form2, i have 1 button. i want to set form1.textbot value when form2 button is clicked then close the form2.

```
form1 button to call form2

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub


this is button form2
 Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As New form1
    x.textbox.Text = "tes"

End Sub
```

i've tried ctype, directcast but its not working. by the way, this form1 is docked to a mainform. i tried to do the same but without form docked, it works, but when it docked, its not working.

Comment: You're creating a new `form1` - so now you have two of them. You need to keep a reference to your existing `form1` and pass it to `Form2` when you create it.

Comment: and how to pass it?

Comment: You're already passing it with `ShowDialog(Me)`. In `Form2` you'd do something like `CType(Me.Owner, form1).textbox.Text = "tes"`.

Comment: The `new` keyword in that code means something. Think about what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found my solution

here's code on form 1

```
Private t1 As String = String.Empty
Private t2As String = String.Empty

 Dim f As New form1()
    If f.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        t1 = f.t1.ToString
        t2 = f.t2.ToString
        textbox.Text = t1
        textbox2.Text = t2
        f.Close()
    End If
```

and here's on form2

```
Public t1 As String
Public t2 As String

Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    If Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        t1 = dgdriver.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString
        t2 = dgdriver.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if you are using default instances.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.textbox.Text = "tes"
    Close()
End Sub
```

Did you really name the text box textbox? Descriptive names can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently doing is creating a new instance of `form1` with the line `Dim x As New form1` - and that means you're not updating the original `form1`.

Since you are passing a reference to `form1` to the `Form2` dialog already, i.e. `.ShowDialog(Me)` then this would work:

```
'form1
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub

'Form2
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CType(Me.Owner, form1).textbox.Text = "tes"
End Sub
```